# NetNamedPipeBinding and username/password authentication

Tags: .net, wcf, security, authentication

I have a WCF service that I expose using different endpoints, one of which uses `NetNamedPipeBinding`. The other endpoints use [a custom username/password validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354513.aspx) to authenticate users, but as far as I can tell, this is not supported by `NetNamedPipeBinding`.

How can I add a custom username/password authentication mechanism to a `NetNamedPipeBinding` with minimal impact on other endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by writing my own custom behavior. I read the article "[Extending WCF with Custom Behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx)" which helped me write a message inspector which appends the username and password as message headers on the client side and verifies these on the service side.

Comment: More than a year later but...would you mind posting a code sample of how you extended NetNamedPipeBinding to allow MessageCredentialType.UserName validation?

Answer (score 0):

With NetNamedPipeBinding has almost no security, since it only works if you are on the same machine. There is only transport level security.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731699.aspx